# How to enable all suggestions in intellisense all the time?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

I am quite new to Microsoft Visual Studio. I am using VS Community 2019. I want to enable all suggestions in intellisense all the time, how can I do that?

For example, I have a vector variable `v2qPenLine` which is a `QVector<QVector<QPen>>`. The vector variable is named in such a way so that I have easy access to it through intellisense. When I try to use it inside `setPen()` method (which is expecting a `QPen` but not a vector of `QPen` I guess) the intellisense does not suggest this vector:

[image]

To have it suggested, I need to click on the `+` button at the bottom and then it suggests the correct variable immediately:

[image]

This behaviour is not convenient at all. How can I change this behaviour of the intellisense so that it suggests only based on the name and do it all the time so that I don't have to click the `+` button at the bottom of the suggestion list? I think there should be a setting for this and so I tried to look up the settings of intellisense but I was unable to change this behaviour. I also couldn't find any reference to this on the internet.

Comment: Could you please share a sample of your code to help us reproduce this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a problem of your VS IDE Intellisense. And you can see that the Intellisense of your environment does have any info about variables, functions, classes ....on the first time. It should show all types on the first time. In your side, it only has the type of methods, quite strange.

[image]

Try the following suggestions:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under Extensions--> Manage Extensions-->Installed to check if there is an extension which caused that.

**2)** close VS, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`

**3)** reset all vs settings under Tools-->Import and Export Settings-->Reset all settings

**4)** close Vs, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder and then restart your project to test again.

**5)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it if there is a new release version

Comment: Thanks! It seems `Reset all Settings` did the trick :)